# Add Page to existing PDF at Workflow completion

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, pdf

We use SharePoint 2010 Workflow to Manage our Change Notice Process.
A PDF is created by the originator, and is linked to the Workflow.  Our auditor wants the Approval history appended to the PDF.

So how would I go about creating a PDF page with the approval history, and appending this page to an existing PDF.  THe actual PDFs are stored in a File Share outside of SharePoint.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common scenario that I deal with every day. You cannot do it using SharePoint's out of the box facilities, but it is relatively easy to achieve by doing some development work or buying a third party utility.

The approval history, when displayed in SharePoint, is an HTML page. So what you need to do is programmatically convert that HTML page to PDF and merge it together with the main document.

As an added bonus you can even convert the source document to PDF automatically, which saves the users from having to do it.

You can find details about how to merge from the various SharePoint Workflow Environments (Nintex Workflow, SharePoint Designer Workflow, Visual Studio Workflow) in this [Knowledge Base Article](http://support.muhimbi.com/entries/23752263-What-PDF-merging-facilities-are-available).

Please note that I wrote that KB article so consider me biased.